# Why doesn't the vacuum of space rip the Earth, or other celestial bodies, like the Sun, apart?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, pressure, free-body-diagram

Since vacuums are a lower pressure than the atmosphere of the earth(and probably many or all other planets) then why doesn't the vacuum of space rip the earth apart or suck all the gasses on it away and distribute them around the universe?

My theory is that it's because earths gravity is strong enough to hold all of the gasses and other particles in.

Comment: Vacuum isn't a force.  Despite what you think, it doesn't "suck".  Rather, in the presence of a vacuum, *pressure* from other sources *pushes* matter (air, whatever) in the direction of the vacuum (because there's nothing pushing back).  In the case of the earth (and the sun), *gravity* pushes air (and the gasses of the sun) inward.

Comment: I was taught that in an area where there are 2 different pressures, they will balance out. For example, if you have a bottle and fill it with compressed air, the air will "shoot" out (for lack of better terms) if you open the bottle because the regular atmospheric pressure is lower than inside the bottle.

Comment: I actually was not taught this in school yet, I taught myself by watching tv. Tell me if I'm incorrect with anything I said.

Comment: Still vacuum sucks. It is what we are doing when we suck. Point is that the vacuum should be enough.

Comment: Yes, absent other forces, the pressure between the open bottle and the outside will "equalize".  But gravity is a substantial force, when considered on a global scale.

Comment: Keep in mind that, although the sea-level air pressure is 14.7psi (101.325 kPa), this does not mean that this much pressure is pushing outward against gravity.  Rather, the pressure at each level of the atmosphere is pushing outward against the pressure of the air just above it, with only a slightly lower pressure pushing back.  Gravity then makes up the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's gravity that holds planets and other celestial bodies together. In particular, a solid object on a planet would have to be moving faster than the planet's [escape velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_velocity) in order to overcome the planet's gravity and go off into space. The Earth's escape velocity, in particular, is about 40,000 km/hour (that's about 25,000 MPH if you're from the U.S.), so essentially no solid objects on Earth move that fast naturally.

However, gasses on a planet do drift off into outer space, which is called [atmospheric escape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_escape). The most common mechanism for that happening is called Jeans escape. In a gas like the atmosphere, the gas molecules move at a range of different speeds, called the [Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution). At any given temperature, most of the gas molecules are moving fairly slowly, but a few of the molecules wind up moving so fast that they're faster than the escape velocity, and the gas molecule goes off into space.

The Sun and other stars have an atmosphere that's much hotter than a planet's atmosphere, which makes it even more likely that a particle will wind up going faster than the star's escape velocity. The particles that escape from the sun like that are called the [solar wind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_wind).

Comment: If gasses escape earth's atmosphere regularly, then how is there still an atmosphere on earth.

Comment: @daniel Because the amount of gas we lose per year is a minute fraction of the total quantity in the atmosphere. Also, the main gas we lose is hydrogen, because its light molecules are relatively fast at a given temperature, and we pick up some fresh hydrogen from the solar wind, and some hydrogen is also produced in the upper atmosphere by ultraviolet light splitting water molecules. Sadly, we lose much of our atmospheric helium to space.

Comment: Also note that Earth receives about 15000 tons of rocks and dust from space per year, some of that stuff contains water, or minerals that contain elements that will eventually contribute to our atmosphere. And volcanic action can dump gases into the atmosphere too.

Answer (score -2):

Because it's not a perfect absolute zero vacuum.

Comment: The question doesn't assume they are a perfect absolute zero vacuum, just lower pressure.